# Listeners only work once

Tags: events, controller, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i am having a problem with my application , suppose there is a listener on a button in a certain panel , the listener works fine and the event gets fired in the first time. However , if i revisit this page the listeners wont work.

i configure the listener in my controller as follows:

```
config: {
  refs:{
         btn : '#mybtn'
       }
  control : { 
         btn : {
                 tap : 'doSmth'
               }
            }
        },


  doSmth : function () {
       //some code goes here
  }


  doS
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your description is not detailed enough. However, I've encountered this issue several times and mainly, it's due to:

- Deactivating / destroying your component. Sencha Touch only sticks listeners to your components **once**, when the associated controllers are initialized.
- You did something that change your component's id.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add `autoDestroy: false` config in your view which contains `mybtn` control.

Answer (score 0):

Adde a more specific selector. Like '#mypanel #mybtn', where #mypanel is parent of button.